# creating a pipe in C

Tags: c, shell, unix, pipe

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Pipe in C UNIX shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7831589/pipe-in-c-unix-shell)

I was trying to create a pipe between 2 child process:
Child1 closes input and outputs to pipe
Child2 closes output and accepts input:

```
        pipe(&fd[0]);                               //Create a pipe
        proc1 = fork();

        //Child process 1
        if (proc1 ==  0)
        {
            close(fd[0]);                           //process1 doenst need to read from pipe
            dup2(fd[1], STD_OUTPUT);
            close(fd[1]);
            execvp(parameter[0], parameter);        //Execute the process
        }

        //Create a second child process
        else
        {
            //Child process 2
            proc2 = fork();
            if (proc2 == 0)
            {
                close(fd[1]);
                dup2(fd[0], STD_INPUT);
                close(fd[0]);
                execvp(parameter2[0], parameter2);
            }
            //Parent process
            else
            {
            waitpid(-1, &status, 0);            //Wait for the child to be done
            }
        }
```

However, I am going wrong somewhere and I don't know exactly where (there aren't any errors, its more of a logic error)

Answer (score 2):

The pipe is backwards.  `fd[1]` is for writing, `fd[0]` is for reading.

**Side note:** `pipe(&fd[0]);` looks a little weird... `pipe(fd);` is equivalent, but (to my eyes) clearer.

Comment: so dup2(fd[1], STD_OUTPUT) should be: dup2(fd[1], STD_INPUT)?

Comment: Yes, although you can use the predefined macros `STDIN_FILENO` and `STDOUT_FILENO`.